# Adding an update node into a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do a update function in this current code. He does not want us to change the student ID, but wants us to change the GPA and the major associated with the current student. He wants us to
create a prompt for the user to enter the student ID number to search for. Also to create a prompt to determine which field the user wished to update then accept new input for that field and change the contents of the appropriate student. I don't want the answer. I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "stuff.h"
#include "staticll.h"

int compareID(void*, void*);
int compareGPA(void*, void*);
int compareMajor(void*, void*);

void main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
struct Node  List[15];
int Begin, current, newStuff, oldStuff;
double oldData;
int(*fnPtr)();

fnPtr = compareMajor;


Begin = 0;

struct Student *stu;

for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
{
    newStuff = FindSpace(List);

    List[newStuff].nodeData = readData(stdin);

    addNode(Begin, List, newStuff);
}

for (int i = Begin; i != -1; i = List[i].nodeLink)
    fprintf(stdout,"%.2f\n",((Stu*)List[i].nodeData));

for (int i = Begin; i != -1; i = List[i].nodeLink)
    free(List[i].nodeData);
}


int  compareID(void *p1, void *p2)
{
    if (((Stu*)p1)->stuID == ((Stu*)p2)->stuID)
        return 0;
    else
    if ((((Stu*)p1)->stuID < ((Stu*)p2)->stuID))
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}

int  compareGPA(void *p1, void *p2)
{
    if (((Stu*)p1)->stuGPA == ((Stu*)p2)->stuGPA)
        return 0;
    else
    if ((((Stu*)p1)->stuGPA < ((Stu*)p2)->stuGPA))
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}

int  compareMajor(void *p1, void *p2)
{
    return strcmp(((Stu*)p1)->stuMajor, ((Stu*)p2)->stuMajor);
}
```

This is the current code I've created for the update function needed.

```
 #include"Stuff.h"

void updateNode(struct Node List[], int current, int *NewData)
{

        int temp1;

    List[current].nodeLink = List[*NewData].nodeData;
    List[*NewData].nodeLink = NewData;

    printf("enter the student ID number ");





}
```

Comment: void main(void){} should be int main(void){} and I think you need **int mfnPtr = compareMajor();**. Also in your code you call **free**, but I don't see where you call **malloc**

Comment: FILE *fp, what exactly does fp here?. You should post the whole code. In your for, how does **i** get updated?

Comment: since the linked list already exists,  start at the 'head' of the list and at each node, check if the studentID is the same as the studentID being searched for.  when it is the same, assign the new GPA to the GPA field and assign the new major to the major field.. all done, no need to malloc(), no need to free() no need to change any link-next pointers

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` )

Comment: At a minimum, please post the struct Node definition.  This statement: `struct Node  List[15];` says the array is pre-defined at 15 entries (and cannot change) so searching for a specific studentID should be very easy.  (always allow for the desired studentID is not in the array of 15 structs)

Comment: regarding this line: `List[current].nodeLink = List[*NewData].nodeData;` why waste space with links when the array is statically allocated?  such links are only useful for two reasons.  1) when sorting the structs, inplace  2) when linking between different structs that are dynamically allocated by calling 'malloc()'

Comment: @Michi as for the FILE *fp is something he added for a future project.